# Bitmap images Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

What is the problem in this code ? Why the firstimage  did not show on XAML page when I am binding the source of image in XAML to firstimage  here in the code?
The class contains the code is not a partial class.

```
if (ImagesAsSource[realty.ObjectId].Count == 0)
//private static Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
{
    Uri img = new Uri(_baseUri, "Assets/back.jpg");
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
    result.UriSource = img;
    // firstimage  is type of ImageSoure
    firstimage  =result;
}

//I tried this:

//private static Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
{
    Uri img = new Uri(_baseUri, "Assets/back.jpg");
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage(img );
    // firstimage  is type of ImageSoure
    firstimage  =result;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to create BitmapImage from URI string.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: You can try code from answer

Comment: @Valin Creating a BitmapImage from a `Uri` (not a URI string) is not a problem, but instead a correct way to create a BitmapImage.

Comment: @user3105491 Please show the XAML where you bind to `firstimage`. Did you make sure that `firstimage` is a public property?

Comment: firstimage is a parameter of type ImageSource in function ,
the job of this function is collect the data and make it as group, so I will call this function from differnt partial class,get group that contains firstimage ,and then Binding in XAML.

Comment: No idea what "parameter in function" means *exactly*. Is it a local variable, or a function argument? Do you return it somewhere? How does the binding look like? Is the binding source property actually updated? You have to post more of your code, otherwise nobody can tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct solution.

```
Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
Uri img = new Uri(_baseUri, "Assets/back.png");
BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage(img);
// firstimage  is type of ImageSoure
firstimage.Source = result;
```

Comment: The class contains this isn't a partial class.

Comment: `firstimage` seems to be no Image control, but a field or property of type ImageSource.

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like this:

```
Uri img = new Uri(_baseUri, "Assets/back.jpg");
var webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(img);
BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage(imageBytes);
```

In fact I don't know constructor for your BitmapImage, so may be you should convert byte[] into Stream

Comment: This is not correct solution, why to use WebClient? What if the app doesn't use Internet?

Comment: You used URI so it seems logical to use webclient to get data from it.

Comment: But they are local URIs, not the Internet URIs.

Comment: What if app doesn't use Internet, should OP tell user to have Internet to run images. It's not a feasible solution & BTW `BitmapImage` doesn't take `byte[]` as parameter.

Comment: -1 for two reasons. First, it does not make any sense to use WebClient for local files. Second, BitmapImage does not have a constructor that takes a byte array as argument.